# Facebook Graph API explorer and missing read_stream permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to test `me/home` api but it complains about missing permission:

```
(#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream
```

The problem is that Get Access Token / Extended Permissions window does not have such entry. I only have:

> ads_management ads_read email manage_pages publish_actions
>   publish_pages read_custom_friendlists read_insights
>   read_page_mailboxes rsvp_event

How can I play with this API in Explorer ?

Answer (score 0):

`read_stream` is deprecated, try with `user_posts` instead.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

> The GET /v2.4/{user_id}/home, GET /v2.4/{user_id}/inbox, and GET /v2.4/{user_id}/notifications operations as well as read_stream, read_mailbox, and manage_notifications permissions are deprecated in v2.4.`

The whole operation is deprecated.

Comment: So there is no ability to get user home feed?